# Maze-game with top-down perspective, each level you need to kill monsters and destroy their dens

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I remember seeing this game in a net-cafe when I was young and didn't know English so I cannot remember the title. I have tried searching "maze game", "labyrinth game" and still haven't found it. Even though the name eludes me, I can recall quite a few details about the game:

Basic info:

- It was around 2000 ~ 2006 that I saw this game.
- It's a PC game, on    Windows (maybe Windows XP)
- It probably is a    Flash game, since I saw    the shortcut on the
  desktop
- The shortcut    icon is a golden circle with    a letter inside (not
  sure about this)

The game intro:

A menacing tower looms in the distance, covered with darkness and thunder. As the player character approaches the tower, a shadowy figure is stalking him from a cliff behind him. It's a werewolf, drooling, finding the time to strike. The monster then lunges from atop the cliff at the player, the player swiftly turns around, draws a pistol and shoots a silver bullet at the monster. The monster falls to the ground, twitching then perishes, the player then turns to face the entrance to the tower.

The main character: A boy with a cape/wizard robe

The gameplay:

- Each level is a top-down, grid-based maze-like level (think
  Bomberman).
- Each level will usually has at least 3 monsters and their dens. At
  first, there only 1 type of monster per level. After some level,
  different types of monster will appear at the same time.
- Each type of monster will behave differently, has a weapon it is weak
  against.
- The player lose a life if the monster hit the player with their
  attack.
- The monster's weakness weapon is spawn randomly around the maze, the
  player need to pick it up to use it, the player can only hold 1
  weapon at a time.
- If the monster is hit with the effective weapon, it dies, if not, it
  will be stunned briefly.
- When a monster dies, its respective dens will start glowing. If the
  player "touches" the dens while it is glowing, it will be destroyed. If
  the player cannot destroy the den while it's vulnerable, it will
  spawn a new monster after a while
- The level is cleared when all of the dens are destroyed.
- Each level has a time limit, when the limit is reached, a
  time-up-time-to-die type of monster will appear and chase the player.
- The player has a special meter at the bottom that is slowly filled
  up. When full, the player can press a button to become invincible for
  a short time.

The monsters:

- Man-eating plant, the "beginner" monster with no special skill. It
  attacks by biting. It can be killed with a poison-gas pump. Its den
  is a plant pot or a pulsing bulb.
- The gremlin, its special ability is it will spawn 2 monsters at the
  same time, both need to be killed to destroy the den. It attacks by
  throwing a wrench at a player. It can be killed with a solar flash
  light. Its den is a well.
- The werewolf, its special ability is it will start charging at the
  player at high speed if it saw the player. It can be killed with a
  silver bullet pistol. Its den is a dog house.
- The witch, its special ability is firing a magic spell at the player
  and turn them to a frog. It can be killed with a spell tome, which
  fire a spell back at the witch and turn it to a frog. Its den is a
  bubbling cauldron.
- The vampire, its special ability is it will retreat backward away
  from the player if the player is holding its weakness weapon, the
  player need to ambush it when it turns a corner. It can be
  killed with a wooden stake. Its den is a vampire coffin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the game [Monster Hunter (warning, TvTropes link)](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/VideoGame/MonsterHunterPC), which was produced by Monkey Byte Studio (or Monkey Byte Development). Some say it came out in 2000, some in 2001, and some in 2002.

This scene looks a lot like the one you spoke about, with the wolf trying to jump him, then he shoots it and then it twitches on the ground as it's dying:

A still frame from that scene:

[image: A werewolf is trying to jump the protagonist of the game, who has a revolver drawn out and ready to shoot. In the opening cinematic of the game, the protagonist shot the werewolf dead.]

I found it by randomly searching `top-down maze game from 2000`, stumbled on [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmyjoystick/comments/c0tuym/pc_late_90s_early_2000s_top_down_maze_game_where/) where someone suggested that game (which actually wasn't the one the reddit asker was looking for).

Comment: As a side note, I searched those keywords on DuckDuckGo. It seems like I'm not having so much luck trying to search that on Google.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the game I was looking for!